# Creating a plot with convex hull in r

Tags: r, plot, convex-hull

I have a task to do for university and i have no idea how to make it. Can i ask for your help. I canot use any extra packages :(

We have data with points

`xi=(xi1, xi2), for i=1,…,n, where n is natural number`.

**My task is :**

- To write a function, which accepts a set of points and gives set of points, which are vertices of the convex hull of a given set of points.
- To Write a function (or set of functions) that for a given set of points on the plane creates a graph containing the convex hull of given points and other given points. Function has to have ability to specify the drawing style of convex hull and points.

I cannot install packages.

Example solution:

```
###Creating a set of random points on the plane
    pts <- list( rnorm(2))
    for(k in 1:20){ pts <- c( pts, list( rnorm(2))) }
    pts
```

Set of random points

```
[[1]]
[1] -0.2895047  0.3938896

[[2]]
[1] 0.5187255 0.1691874

[[3]]
[1] 0.2310706 0.1311234

[[4]]
[1] -0.44087647  0.07283041

[[5]]
[1]  0.9438115 -1.1034222

[[6]]
[1] 0.9342882 0.9032668

[[7]]
[1] -0.3655531  1.0130261

[[8]]
[1] -2.268272 -1.278624

[[9]]
[1]  2.021061 -2.705479

[[10]]
[1] -0.9460602 -0.1185306

[[11]]
[1] -1.4656782 -0.8536016

[[12]]
[1]  1.0060148 -0.9254827

[[13]]
[1] -0.1493196  1.3880502

[[14]]
[1]  0.4846496 -0.8680879

[[15]]
[1] -0.03187148  1.03490764

[[16]]
[1] 0.3078759 0.8329899

[[17]]
[1]  1.225831 -1.492936

[[18]]
[1] -1.64684601 -0.06100802

[[19]]
[1] -0.08985374  0.62738174

[[20]]
[1] -0.8206645  0.3503755

[[21]]
[1] -0.1374857  0.4190813
```

I should create a function listpoints(pts), which list points of convex hull

```
convHull( pts)
[[1]]
[1]  2.021061 -2.705479

[[2]]
[1] -2.268272 -1.278624

[[3]]
[1] -1.64684601 -0.06100802

[[4]]
[1] -0.1493196  1.3880502

[[5]]
[1] 0.9342882 0.9032668

[[6]]
[1]  2.021061 -2.705479
null device 
          1
```

And create simple plot

```
png( "./fig1.png")
plotPoints( pts, col = "white")
addPoints( convHull( pts), pch = 20, cex = 2, col = "red")
addRegion( convHull( pts), col = rgb(1, 0, 0, 0.1), border = "red")
addPoints( pts, pch = 20, col = "black")
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: Have you seen the function `chull` ?

Comment: Yes i have. But the problem is that i cannot use other packages

Comment: chull is in base R

Comment: It sounds like they're asking you to construct your own convex hull algorithm. The simplest one is probably the [gift wrapping algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_wrapping_algorithm). It's way slower than modern techniques but probably the easiest to code. You can find lots of resources online about the algorithm. It will be a challenge to code and you gotta know your vector geometry